# No autocompletion for other python class in PyCharm

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I am a beginner with Python, in this loop i trying to use the methods of the variable "data_point"
Behind the variable "data_point" is a simple getter and setter class, nevertheless in the autocompletion of PyCharm it shows me only 2 methods instead of all.
What do I have to do to see all methods of this class?[image]

I have added the type, but the behavior is the same

[image]

This is my model class with getter and setter
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate `data_points` as a list of your class

```
def create_a_subplot(self, ax, data_points: list[YourClass]):
    ...
```

Prior to version 3.9 you need to use [typing.List](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)

```
from typing import List

def create_a_subplot(self, ax, data_points: List[YourClass]):
    ...
```

Comment: I added the type but it is not working. I have edited my question

Comment: @User1751 can you add the class/type to your question?